# How to set Sitecore Droptree source to the item itself

Tags: asp.net, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

I want to set the source of a droptree to the item so every time I create an instance of that template I can select it's children. Obviously I can't add the ID of the item to the template as it will be different for every instance of the template.

I tried `$id` in the vain hope that that might work but it didn't.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can just use a query and simply set the source to a relative path:

```
query:./*
```

This should set the source to the children of the current node.

*Bonus: you can use most query expressions as source, making it possible to filter items based on templates or more complex operations. Check out the [query doc at SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf) to get started.*

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work when added to the Source field in the template builder. I read the document and tried a few things from there (e.g. `@@ID`) but none of it sets the source correctly.

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using? This worked for Sitecore 6.2.0 (100507).

Comment: Yeah, I just re-tried it all again and it's working. Very strange to be honest - it really wasn't working before! Thanks, just what I was looking for. =)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use simple XPath queries such as self:: or parent:: . For sets of items it could be `descendant::` or `child::` . But in your case I believe it will be **`self::`**

Comment: To expand on this, the source would be: `query:self::`